# React - Redux: All the data is replacing with the last payload

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using redux to store my data. Initially, the initial state is an empty array ([]), the first time I send the data, the data stores correctly, here is my code:

```
const cartReducer = createReducer([])({
  [types.ADD_TO_CART]: (state, action) => {
    let toReturn = [];

    state.map((item, idx) => {
      toReturn.push(item)
    })


    if (toReturn.length == 0) {

      let obj = {
        header: action.payload.header,
        menu: [
          {
            id_res_menu: action.payload.id_res_menu,
            is_menu: action.payload.is_menu,
            combo: action.payload.combo,
          },
        ],
      };

      toReturn.push(obj);
      return [obj]
    }
    else{
      if(action.payload.is_menu == "S"){
        
        return toReturn.map((item, idx) => {
          if(item.header.id_pla_user == action.payload.header.id_pla_user && item.header.id_res_restaurant == action.payload.header.id_res_restaurant){
            let obj = {
              id_res_menu: action.payload.id_res_menu,
              is_menu: action.payload.is_menu,
              combo: action.payload.combo,
            }
          
            return {
                ...item,
                menu: [
                  ...item.menu,
                  obj
                ]
              }
          }
        })

      }
    }
```

First, I copy the actual state to a variable called toReturn, and in this variable i make the changes.
Then, I verify if the copy of the state (toReturn) length is 0, if it's 0, I push the created object to the array and return it to the state.

The obj scheme is the next one:

```
header: {
  id_user: 1,
  id_res: 1
}
combo:[
  {
    quantity: 1,
    category: "salad",
    name: "caesar salad"
  },
  {
    quantity: 1,
    category: "spaghetti",
    name: "pesto"
  }
]
```

The first time I dispatch the action, it works good, the data is stored correctly, but in the second time, the data is replaces enterely like this:

Payload:

```
header: {
  id_user: 1,
  id_res: 1
}
combo:[
{
  quantity: 1,
  category: "soup",
  name: "pumpkin soup"
},

{
  quantity: 1,
  category: "frying",
  name: "fried chicken"
]
```

Stored Data:

```
state: [
  {
    header: {
      id_user: 1,
      id_res: 1
    },
    menu:[
      {
        combo:[
          {
            quantity: 1,
            category: "soup",
            name: "pumpkin soup"
          },
          {
            quantity: 1,
            category: "frying",
            name: "fried chicken"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        combo:[
          {
            quantity: 1,
            category: "soup",
            name: "pumpkin soup"
          },
          {
            quantity: 1,
            category: "frying",
            name: "fried chicken"
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

The last payload is replacing all the existing data (**pumpkin soup** & **fried chicken**), if I add another, the third payload replace all the data, so on.

Additionally, in the second time, if I print the stored data before i make the changes, the console shows me that in the state is currently the last payload (pumpkin soup and fried chicken) I don't know if the console.logs are processed finally, after the operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I push the created object to the array and return it to the state.

What you are actually doing is updating a local variable `toReturn`.  This variable is not part of the state and never becomes part of the state.  Despite the name, you don't actually `return toReturn`!

```
toReturn.push(obj);
return [obj]
```

Instead you `return [obj]`. This is an array with one element which is the item that you just added.  This single-item array replaces your entire state.

In a Redux Toolkit reducer you can either modify the existing state or return a new state.  If you are modifying then you should not `return` anything.

---

I'm not fully understanding what your reducer is *supposed* to be doing, but try this:

```
const cartReducer = createReducer([], {
  [types.ADD_TO_CART]: (state, action) => {
    // separate payload into a header and object
    const { header, ...obj } = action.payload;

    // find a matching object in state, if one exists
    const match = state.find(
      (item) =>
        item.header.id_user === header.id_user &&
        item.header.id_res === header.id_res
    );

    // if there was a match found, update that item
    if (match) {
      match.menu.push(obj);
    }

    // if not, add a new item to state
    else {
      state.push({
        header,
        menu: [obj]
      });
    }
  }
});
```